# How to make leg bones children of torso bone in Blender?

Tags: 2d, blender, skeletal-animation

I'm a complete Blender novice and I'm trying to create a humanoid skeleton. I'm having problems figuring out how to make my leg bones children of the torso bone. Here's how my skeleton looks like:

[image]

As you can see from the bone hierarchy, the legs are not children of the torso. This is because I extruded them from the lower part of the torso bone. Is there any way I can fix this?

Also, on another note, would this be a good skeleton for 2D animations?

Answer (score 3):

Just parent them to the "Torso" (using `Ctrl P` and keep the offset).

It doesn't look like a very flexible skeleton, especially the rotation  on the leg bones is bad (they are twisted) .. that's something you should definitely avoid. Other than that, it really depends on the type of animation you want to do. You could also search the web for some human-rigs or [tutorials](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/12/12/blender-introduction-to-character-rigging/), that might give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

**The bummzack's answer is right and technically the good one.**

But I will add this answer to encourage you and anybody else to try changing your point of view every time you encounter a problem. Too much often, peoples (including me indeed) doesn't step back (in their mind ^^) to have a better view of the problem.

Here is a very simple example; if you can't link the legs to the torso because you can't (in fact you can as Bummzack said) or don't know how to link them, step back and try step forward another way: can you construct you model from another bone?

I don't know if you tried, but obviously yes you can if you start from the head.

[image]

This skeleton isn't perfect nor it does necessary fits your animations needs (I didn't rotated bones the right way etc...) but that's just a bone linking example and I'm a Blender Rookie too, so I might be wrong. But the important idea is that we need to try others perspective when encountering a problem.